# How to send data from Android to Django

Tags: java, android, python, django, post

I can't find the problem with POST data, I have django app deployed on Heroku and android app that needs to send data to it when user finishes game. When I tested data saving without POST method (hardcoded values) it worked. Can anybody tell me where is the problem in my code?

urls.py

```
url(r'^scorepost/', 'scorepost'),
```

view.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def scorepost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        email = string(request.POST['email'])
        difficulty = string(request.POST['difficulty'])
        time = string(request.POST['time'])
        moves = string(request.POST['moves'])
        score = string(request.POST['score'])

        user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=email)
        Highscore.objects.create(user_id = user.id, difficulty = difficulty, time = time, moves = moves, score = score)
        return HttpResponse("Score saved")

    return HttpResponse("Score not saved")
```

android

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://testdjangoandroid.herokuapp.com/scorepost/");

try {
    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user_email));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("difficulty", Integer.toString(difficulty)));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", Long.toString(totalTime)));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("moves", Integer.toString(totalMoves)));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("score", Long.toString(totalScore)));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

    httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: What django version are you using? In case of >= 1.5: have you set `ALLOWED_DOMAINS` setting appropriately?

Comment: `email` is not used, and `user` is not defined. Do you receive any kind of error at all ?

Comment: what are the symptoms of the error ?

Comment: @alecxe I can't find the ALLOWED_DOMAINS in the settings, can you tell me how and where to do that?

Comment: @aleksandar oops, the setting is called ALLOWED_HOSTS, see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts).

Comment: I fixed the error. I had to put POST method in the AsyncTask.